# Errno 22 Invalid argument \\:\\ added

Tags: django

I am exporting a django project from a computer that runs Ubutnu to another that runs Windows 10. I've exported the environment with `pip install -r requeriments.txt` and everything seems to work fine, since, for example, `python manage.py migrate` is working properly.

The server starts fine with `python manage.py runserver`, however, when I open the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/home in my browser I get the following error:

> IOError at /home/ [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
>   u'C:\Users\myusername\Envs\myenv\myproject\:\HomePage.html'

The views are correctly setup because the project was running OK in ubuntu. The problem seems to be that the HomePage.html, which is supposed to be located in `...\\myproject\\marketingApp\\templates\\HomePage.html`, is being looked for in `...\\myproject\\:\\HomePage.html` and I don't know how/where to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/home by adding my project folder path `'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Envs\\myenv\\myproject'` directly into the TEMPLATES dict:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Envs\\myenv\\myproject'
                ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug':DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.core.context_processors.media",
                "django.core.context_processors.static",
                "django.core.context_processors.tz"
            ],
        },
    },
]
```